# Passing text into Windows cmd line using a python script

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, popen

I am trying to write a simple python script that will open the Windows cmd line, change to a specified directory, and then input the text: 'Test.exe -blah -blahblah etc...' in order to run my Test.exe executable with my specified parameters from the cmd line.

The code I have so far is the following:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe', cwd=r'C:\PythonTestScripts')
```

This code successfully launches the windows cmd.exe, and changes the directory to the specified cwd above, but I have no idea how to pass text into the cmd window from Python.

I have tried passing it as a string argument within the subprocess.Popen brackets, I have also tried assigning PIPE to the stdin and stdout with not much luck. I am familiar with simple coding from Uni, but I am not familiar with Python's syntax or scripting.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of your issues may be that cmd.exe doesn't exit once you've started it.
I was successful passing the `/C` argument to `cmd.exe`, which tell it to exit after processing the command.

This works:

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

my_command = "dir *.log"
with Popen([r"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe","/C",my_command], stdout=PIPE, cwd=r'C:\Temp') as proc:
    print(proc.stdout.read().decode().replace("\r\n","\n"))
```